# What is a self reference in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Currently I am reading `The Ruby Programming Language` and it has mentioning of `self` in many places and I am not able to understand it's exact use. Is its behaviour similar to `this` pointer in C++.What all difference those two have?(I am not asking about the pointer dereferencing or any C++ specific things, in general) And when do we use `self.something` in our ruby code?

Comment: `self` evaluates to the current object. Try `p self` whenever you are curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a variable that points to the object whose scope the current code is in.  You would use `self.something` when calling a class method on that object.
For instance, if you had the following method:

```
class Foo
    def self.bar 
       puts "Class method!"
    end 
end
```

You would call the `bar` method by calling `Foo.bar`.

Comment: Is it like static method in C++? All instances of a class have same copy of the method?

Comment: Instances have instance methods called on them, whereas this example is a class method